# Has Arcsinh ever been considered as a neural network activation function?

Tags: neural-networks, sigmoid-curve

The function 
$y = arcsinh(x)=ln(x+\sqrt{x^2+1})$
has some nice features that I could imagine being useful as an activation function in a neural network. It has sigmoid behaviour around zero, but far from the centre exhibits logarithmic growth which means the slope of the function doesn't diminish nearly as quickly as the sigmoid function, which means the problem of one neuron becoming 'stuck' in a region where the slope is vanishingly small (and therefore can't move from its large value) is avoided. 
[image: Arcsinh function]
I suspect there's a problem with computation - I don't know how arcsinh is normally calculated, but it's probably too computationally intensive to be efficient compared to other activation functions.

I've not seen any evidence of Archsinh used or even considered anywhere. Are my guesses about its features and drawbacks accurate?

Comment: Random googling  yielded https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7531

Comment: I'm sure this has been tried before. I've more commonly seen $\tanh$ activations, as anecdotally they do slightly better than sigmoids in terms of convergence speed (for example in LSTMS), and they immediately give you an output in $[-1,1]$ as opposed to sigmoids (which you could try shifting/scaling).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I tried it. Yes it is slower to compute than other functions (e.g. tanh, arctan, softsign), in gfortran anyway. And I found other drawbacks: the mean squared error was usually worse than other functions after same number of epochs. And it could not tolerate as high a learning rate as others before going unstable. I was only doing simple classifier with 1 or 2 hidden layers. I did wonder like you whether the slow decay of the derivative would help. Maybe it does in deep learning (many layers)?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/359336)

Comment: Thanks for going and actually trying it out. The slowness of computation is as expected, but the MSE being worse is slightly surprising, as I would expect it to be somewhat similar to other activation functions. I'll accept this answer, but was also wondering if you could provide some facts and figures too?

Comment: @Pedro Valdez Now that I've thought about a bit more, it makes sense. Converging towards zero for at least part of the function is very important for a useful activation function. It means the activation function is fitting a curve somewhere, whilst not interfering elsewhere. Any arbitrary shape can be fitted by bricks because the shape of any given brick is a strictly local thing. Arcsinh, to put it in a handwavey way, is non-local. It's doing something everywhere along the real line. Sure the behaviour is logarithmic as you go further out, but it still tends to infinity.

Comment: Which means that any function you're trying to fit that has both a steep slope near the centre and limiting behaviour towards a constant value elsewhere (such as a gaussian distribution with small $\sigma$), isn't going to be fitted well by an Arcsinh function.